# Html not wrapping properly

Tags: html, css, sass

This is a simple one I know.
I have a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-choice rectangle" (click)="setQuestion(question, !question.active, $event)" [ngClass]="{ 'active': question.active }"
  href="#">
  <span class="fa fa-square"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-check-square"></span>
  <span class="title">{{ question.description }}</span>
</a>
```

The `fa` classes are hidden depending on the button state (I am using bootstrap btw). The css for it looks like this:

```
.btn-choice {
    @include make-text-sizes($h1-sizes);
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    color: white !important;
    background-color: $midnight;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: left;

    .header {
        padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    }

    .title {
        padding-right: 40px;
        display: block;
    }

    .fa {
        float: right;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 7px; // Center vertically?
    }

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        font-weight: 400 !important;
        background-color: $cyan;
        .fa-square {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    &:active,
    &.active {
        font-weight: 400 !important;
        background-color: $cyan;
        .fa-check-square {
            display: block;
        }
        .fa-square {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to get the title to have some padding so it never overlaps the "square checkboxes", but I cannot get it to work.
As you can see, the `.title` is set to be a block and I have set some padding-right.
If I examine my element I can see the that outline is within the link, but the text just continues through it.

Here is a codepen with the issue:

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/LJZQqb

Comment: It might be worth adding a tag for whichever CSS pre-processor you're using, as it's a style issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I knew it would be simple; seems I can just add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the `.title` and that fixed my issue.

Comment: See answer above?

Comment: Than please select any of the answers as solution that includes that particular information.

Comment: Sounds good, but I can't accept my own solution for 2 days after posting it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have a solution -

The main changes being -

```
.btn-choice {
   padding: 20px 30px;
}

.title {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  white-space: initial;
}
```

https://codepen.io/DarianSteyn/pen/eLzMzp

Comment: This is a solution, but my one requires no widths to be set, so doesn't have issues with window resizing. I would suggest that my solution is better for that reason.

Comment: Please check the answer below I have added. Widths are not required.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the codepen for you. https://codepen.io/charumaheshwari/pen/NLrMXb. 
Idea is to give padding-right:40px to "title"

```
.title {
    display: block;
    padding-right:40px;
    white-space: initial;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I adapted your example and used flexbox and also as already mentioned overwrote the `white-space` from the bootstrap standard.

See the forked codepen: https://codepen.io/dreitzner/pen/bxevvP

Comment: that is not doing anything :o

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't save the last progress. Pls check again. The title wraps and has a padding on the right.